# How do I draw a labeled diagram like following

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

[image]

I believe there is help to draw the nodes and edges using Tex, but how do I draw the text on top of the edges?

Comment: Do you know the `\draw (A) --node[above]{abc} (B);` syntax of Ti*k*Z? It could help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `automata` library allows you to draw something of this sort very easily. All I did is to subject the example on p. 563 of the pgfmanual to minor changes, and followed [Skillmon's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470120/how-do-i-draw-a-labeled-diagram-like-following#comment1184095_470120) ;-).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,auto] 
\node[state,initial] (1) {$1$}; 
\node[state] (2) [right=of 1] {$2$}; 
\node[state,accepting] (3) [right=of 2] {$3$}; 
\draw  (1) edge [loop above] node {$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (1)
(1) edge[->] node[above]{$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 1\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (2)
(2) edge[->] node[above]{$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 1\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (3)
(3) edge [loop above] node {$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can tweak it. (EDIT: increased `double distance`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2.5cm,auto,initial text=,
loop above/.style={min distance=10mm,in=60,out=120,looseness=5}] 
\node[state,initial] (1) {$1$}; 
\node[state] (2) [right=of 1] {$2$}; 
\node[state,accepting,double distance=2pt] (3) [right=of 2] {$3$}; 
\begin{scope}[font=\small]
\draw[->]  (1) edge [loop above] node {$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (1)
(1) edge node[above]{$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 1\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (2)
(2) edge node[above]{$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 1\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (3)
(3) edge [loop above] node {$\begin{bmatrix}\#\\ 0\\ 0\\{} *\end{bmatrix}$} (3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I did tweak it a little to add multiple labels. Does anybody know if I could change(increase) the width of the concentric circle at node 3? At first glance, it doesnt seem clear that node 3 is the accepting state.

Comment: @GermanShepherd Yes, this is just a `double` line. Try e.g. `\node[state,accepting,double distance=2pt] (3) [right=of 2] {$3$}; ` to increase the distance.